# How can I fix this issie with logging in users and storing them in a firestore database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This code i used to store users in firebase.

```
this.db
        .doc('/users/' + user.uid)
        .set({
          name: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
        })
        .then(() => console.log('user saved successfully'))
        .catch((reason: any) => console.log('user save failed:', reason));
```

Users also have a isAdmin property that gets set elsewhere.
When I login as a new user, the user gets a name and email.

If i make the user admin i can visit admin only pages.
issue is, if i refresh on an admin page i get kicked of the page.
I think the issue is the set method, since it doesnt contain the isAdmin property

When I use update instead of set, it works fine when I refresh, but now I cant create new records for new users.

What is the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to merge the data in your set call with the existing data (if any), which you can do by specifying set options:

```
this.db
    .doc('/users/' + user.uid)
    .set({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email,
    }, { merge: true }) //
```

Also see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document

Comment: This didnt fix it, when I refresh my page on an admin authorized page, I get redirected to the home page, since the isAdmin property isnt part of the set. When I use update this isnt an issue, and it should only use .set for creating user, since the refresh bug isnt noticable here